# Reset Password cannot find username

Tags: login, password-recovery, recovery-mode, reset

I'm trying to reset the password to the base administrative/main account on my Ubuntu system. In the recovery shell, I will type `passwd <user>` and it will give me an error output saying that user `<user>` does not exist.

I have verified that the user does indeed exist in the system via

`cat /etc/passwd | grep USERNAME`

What could the issue be that it cannot find the user in question?

Comment: Are you literally typing `passwd <user>`?

Comment: Yes @OwenHines literally that, and its sudo passwd <user> variation

Comment: Is the user that you're changing the password for's name actually `<user>`?

Comment: Also its not a duplicate @Elder Geek, since I'm following the instructions there in explained, but I can't perform the actual reset

Comment: @OwenHines no the username is not actually <user>

Comment: `CAT ABUSE !!!!`- http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21664624-Do-You-Abuse-the-cat -  post the output of `grep USERNAME /etc/password` `cat | grep` is poor form, lol. Also output `ls /home` and the exact command you ran and error message. Simply stating it is not working is not helping us to solve your problem.

Comment: Please also include the prompt in your [edit] as it will abundantly clear to us whether you did indeed drop to a root shell as instructed in the duplicate question